# How to Manipulate TIFF header values in Python (PIL)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I can read in a TIFF image file via PIL just fine...

```
im = Image.open('FRONT200BW_1.TIF')
```

I can see the TIFF headers via:

```
im.tag[270]
'returned description'
```

Here's where I'm hitting a brick wall. I have a requirement to fiddle with Artist (315), Date_Time (306), Document_Name (269), Image_Description (270) and Page_Name (285) and then save the file back out to disk with no other changes to the image data nor to any other header values / tags.

It appears that I'm supposed to be able to do something like this:

```
im.tag[270] = 'my new description'
```

But when I do that, funny things happen....

If I do a save() on that file and inspect it, it doesn't have the new description header and in fact loses ALL header values.

When I inspect the value prior to monkeying with it via

```
im.tag.tags
```

What I get is a dictionary looking thing returned with a string for the description that was previously present in the file. After I alter it as stated above and look at im.tag.tags, it changes the value of key 270 from a string to a tuple. And....like I said, saving it appears to wipe out all of the headers.

How do I change these header values?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2000-September/001190.html) is of help?

Comment: [Tiffany](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tiffany/) is a python package that looks like it might be of help

Comment: I don't think Tiffany is what I'm after and I'd like to avoid importing another package if I can avoid it all costs. The other link is something I ran across googling but I'm not sure how to interpret it other than it sounds like there may be some known funkiness with TIFF images and header values in PIL. At this point, I'd be happy for someone to confirm at least what the expected way to do what I'm trying to do would be.

Comment: You can always look at PIL's Python source and see what's going on. It should be in your `Python/Lib/site-packages/PIL`. You might also want to try using [`Pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0) which is a more modern fork of PIL.

Comment: I have other third party libraries with PIL as a dependency and I really don't want to introduce a new one if I can avoid it. I have looked at the source and short of trying to read and understand the inards of TIFF I don't see anything obviously wrong with what I'm doing and in fact as I mentioned, it was a comment in the source code that led me to believe that I can do what I'm trying to do. Googling around more is leading me to a conclusion that both PIL and Pillow both are broken when it comes to re-encoding headers on a save. I may be forced to find a different solution here.

Comment: I wrote [Tiffany](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tiffany/) long time ago when PIL was incomplete regarding Tiff and [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) was not mature.
Meanwhile, Tiffany is a bit redundant, because Pillow seems to do it all.
Actually, none seems to have direct support for changing tags.
Should I consider to add such functionality? Proposals, please?

Comment: @ChristianTismer Yass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested...I gave up on PIL working for this. I'm convinced that there's a bug in there and I don't have the time to fix it. If you monkey with any of the headers then it blows away ALL of the header information on Image.save().

Instead I installed libtiff libraries (yum install libtiff on redhat-based systems) and then used subprocess.call('tiffset -s X ') where X was the header id to change from my python code.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully this will still be of some help.

The reason why your changes to the header doesn't get saved, or indeed no tags at all get saved, is that you are not saving it correctly. As I understand it, when doing changes to a loaded image the changed image exists in memory only and becomes disassociated with the file it came from and thus the TIFF-specific headers are deleted.

To save an image to a TIFF file with headers you therefore have to:

1. Keep a reference to the `tag` attribute (which is a `PIL.TiffImagePlugin.ImageFileDirectory` object) right after loading the image.
2. Make your changes to the `ImageFileDirectory` as you specified.
3. You have to import the module `PIL.TiffImagePlugin`
4. This `PIL.TiffImagePlugin` module has an attribute `WRITE_LIBTIFF` that has to be set to False.
5. When you finally call the `save` method you need to pass it a keyword argument `tiffinfo` set to the `ImageFileDirectory` object you referenced after first loading the image.

This may or may not require that you are using the Pillow fork of PIL, though I'm not really sure.

For more info and code example see: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/983

Comment: You can do that with both [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) and [Tiffany](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tiffany) in this way, and PIL will work, too. It is just not an official way with a defined API. It might make sense to create such an API and plug that into the three packages.